# What is the meaning of synchronization in special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, time, causality

Suppose there are two observers $A$ and $B$ (or reference frames if you will), let us label their time coordinates by $t_A$ and $t_B$ respectively.

When  we say we synchronize the clocks of $A$ and $B$, we impose $ t_A= t_B $, wouldn't this mean that if $t_A=t_B$ for the same events, what is simultaneous for $A$ is simultaneous for $B$?

Comment: #t_a=t_b=0. does this help?

Answer (score 1):

No, if A and B are moving relative to each other, you can only make their two times the same at a given point- everywhere else they will be out of synch. You mind find it easier to visualise if you forget about time for a moment and consider a spatial analogy as follows...

Suppose you and I are each make a paper map of map a town using x and y coordinates, with a particular landmark being our common origin. When we have finished, we realised that we have each used a different baseline, so our x and y frames are tilted relative to each other. At the landmark we each agree that our respective x and y coordinates are zero, but everywhere else your x and y coordinates are different to mine.

Now carry that principle over to time. We can have a common origin of time at a particular point, but our two planes of simultaneity will be tilted (just as our maps were in the spatial example), so everywhere away from our common origin we will disagree upon the time.

Comment: This is a good answer but does not really nicely describe the way time differs at all other points

Answer (score 0):

> My question is when says that synchronize the clocks of A and B is
> make to tA=tB ,what they mean is that tA=tB for the same events that
> is what is simultaneous for A is simultaneous for B?

No, A and B syncing their clocks does not necessarily mean that events that are simultaneous in A frame will be simultaneous in B frame.
That will be the case ONLY if A and B are not moving with respect to each other.

Generally, in SR examples when they say this, they mean that the events of A clock ticking 0 and B clock ticking 0 are simultaneous in both the frames.
That does not mean that the events of A clock ticking 5 and B clock ticking 5 will be simultaneous as well. That would only be the case , if they are not moving with respect to each other

Comment: so  what you mean if the observers are moving in relation with each other than there is  just one moment that the events are simultaneous?

Comment: @amiltonmoreira If the observers are moving relative to each other, then, in general, 2 events that are simultaneous in A's frame WILL NOT be simultaneous in B's frame